# RDLC How to hide data if amount is 0.00

Tags: report, rdlc

How can I hide the Php 0.00 since it's zero amount? I used

```
=IIf((Fields!cdr_charge_amount.Value <= 0.00), True, False)
```

But still, the Php 0.00 is appearing.

Below are my screenshots of my project.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response. Select the whole row and under Properties, select Visibility>Hidden>Expression and type the following code:

```
=IIF(SUM(CDbl(IIF(Fields!cdr_call_type_code.Value = "CEL",Fields!cdr_charge_amount.Value,0))) > 0, False, True)
```

I just changed the "CEL" to IDD or NDD per row.

Comment: In your question it wasn't clear that you wanted to hide the entire rows. Glad you were able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The expression you defined seems ok to me. The issue might be that the value is slightly larger than *"0.00"*, for example *"0.001"* would mean that the comparison is false. You should probably format the value properly before comparing it.

A simple solution would be to change the value expression of the TextBox to something like this:

```
=IIf(Fields!cdr_charge_amount.Value < 0.01, "",("Php " &  FORMAT(...)))
```

This will print an empty string if the condition is true. I usually avoid the hidden property because it can be confusing when working with rectangles for example.